# Create Range of Hours in Python

Tags: python, datetime, date

So I'm looking to take input such as 7:00 AM as a start time, and say, 10:00 PM as an endtime, and then compare a set of times (also in the form of 8:00 AM, 3:00 PM, etc) to see if those time are or aren't in the range of time. Is there a good way to create a "day" that has a range of hours (the endtimes can be as late as 4:00 AM, so I was figuring I would go from 6:00 AM - 5:59 AM instead of midnight - 11:59 PM, if that's possible) that I can check times against?

For example: `starttime = 8:00 AM, endtime = 3:00 AM`, and checking `time = 7:00 AM` would return time as being out of the range.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`datetime`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) parsing and comparison capabilities:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

def parse_time(s):
    ''' Parse 12-hours format '''
    return datetime.strptime(s, '%I:%M %p')

starttime = parse_time('8:00 AM')
endtime   = parse_time('3:00 AM')
if endtime < starttime:
   # add 1 day to the end so that it's after start
   endtime += timedelta(days=1)

checked_time = parse_time('7:00 AM')

# Can compare:
print starttime <= checked_time < endtime
```

Comment: Thanks, this should solve my problem of the 3:00 AM being after 8:00 AM.

Answer (score 2):

I'd probably use the [datetime](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html) library. Use `strptime()` on your input strings, then you can compare the `datetime` objects directly.

Answer (score 1):

Convert all times into a 24-hour format, taking minutes and seconds as fractions of hours, then just compare them as numbers to see if a time lies in an interval.

Answer (score 1):

Python's datetime.* classes already support comparison:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime(2012,10,2,10) > datetime.datetime(2012,10,2,11)
False
>>> datetime.datetime(2012,10,2,10) > datetime.datetime(2012,10,2,9)
True
```

So all you have to do is declare a class TimeRange, with two members startTime and endTime. Then a "inside" function can be as simple as:

```
def inside(self, time):
    return self.startTime <= time and time <= self.endTime
```

Comment: Actually, comparison is even easier than that in Python: `self.startTime <= time <= self.endTime`.