# How do I determine if current time is within a specified range when the start time is greater than the end time?

Tags: python, python-datetime

Is there way to check if your current time is in a time range when the end time is less than the start time?

All the examples and answers I have seen are when the start time is less than the end time. For example

```
import datetime

start_time = datetime.time(1)
end_time = datetime.time(12)

for i in range(0,24):
    now = datetime.time(i)
    if start_time <= now <= end_time:
        print "%s in range" % now
    else:
        print "%s not in range" % now
```

Will return correctly if `now` is in range or not.

However this approach doesn't work the end time is greater than the start time.

```
start_time = datetime.time(22)
end_time = datetime.time(12)
```

This returns `not in range` for all times.

If possible I'd like to avoid doing something like this:

```
if start_time < end_time:
    # do start <= now <= end comparison 
else:
    # check if now is past midnight or before midnight
    # then check against start or end time
```

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111961/create-range-of-hours-in-python#answer-10112119

Comment: This is very dependant on how you treat time. Looking at a clock with two hands pointing to different times all other time periods are between them in some direction. Using a linear approach of 0hr - 24hr things are different.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to ignore the idea of time being wrapped over midnight, you can easily fix this in a single line.

Once you have the start and endtimes, you can sort them with [`sorted()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted) which returns a new sorted list, and then reassign them back to the satrt and end times.

So put this line in and it should be fine.

```
start_time,end_time=sorted([start_time,end_time])
```

Here is a [complete working script on codepad](http://codepad.org/QHpHT5oU) to confirm.